# Android Studio ругается на @override (Method does not override method from its superclass)

Tags: java, android-studio, override

Всем доброе утро, день, вечер, ночь). Android studio ругается на САМЫЙ ПОСЛЕДНИЙ @override в самом конце кода. Помогите пожалуйста, новичок, сижу, туплю. ВРОДЕ бы всё как по видеоуроку делаю, но там работает а у меня нет)

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Level1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    Dialog dialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.universal);

        final ImageView basic_left = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.basic_left);
        basic_left.setClipToOutline(true);
        final ImageView basic_right = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.basic_right);
        basic_right.setClipToOutline(true);

        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //Вызов диалогового окна в начале игры
        dialog = new Dialog(this); //Создаём диалоговое окно
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//Скрываем заголовок диалогового окна
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.prewievdialog);//путь к макету диалогового окна
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));//прозрачный фон диалогового окна
        dialog.setCancelable(false); //окно нельзя закрыть кнопкой назад

        //Кнопка закрывающая диалоговое окно - начало
        TextView btnclose = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnclose_prw);
        btnclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //обрабатываем нажатие кнопки - начало
                try {
                    //вернуться назад к выбору уровней начало

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Level1.this, GameLevels.class); //объявлено о намерении о переходе
                    startActivity(intent); //запуск намерения
                    finish(); //закрыть этот класс

                    //вернуться назад к выбору уровней - конец

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //обрабатываем нажатие кнопки - конец
                }
                dialog.dismiss();//закрываем диалоговое окно
            }
        });
        //Кнопка закрывающая диалоговое окно - конец

        //Кнопка продолжить - начало

        Button btncontinue = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttoncontinue);
        btncontinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss(); //Закрываем диалоговое окно
            }
        });

        //Кнопка продолжить - конец

        dialog.show();//показать диалоговое окно

        //Кнопка назад - начало

        Button button_back_level1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_back_level1);
        button_back_level1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Level1.this, GameLevels.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //Здесь кода не будет
                }
            }
        });

        //Кнопка назад - конец


    }

    //Системная кнопка назад - начало
    @Override  //ANDROID STUDIO ругается на этот override (Method does not override method from its superclass)
    public void OnBackPressed() {
        //обрабатываем нажатие кнопки назад - начало
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Level1.this, GameLevels.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Здесь кода не будет
        }
        //Обрабатываем нажатие кнопки назад - конец
    }

}
    //Системная кнопка назад - конец
```

Comment: //Системная кнопка назад - начало - ориентир в самом конце
    @Override  //ANDROID STUDIO ругается на этот override (Method does not override method from its superclass)

Answer (score 3):

Ваша проблема в элементарной опечатке

```
 @Override  //ANDROID STUDIO ругается на этот override (Method does not override method from its superclass)
 public void OnBackPressed() {...}
```

Первая буква имени метода должна быть маленькой:

```
@Override  //ANDROID STUDIO больше не будет ругаться :)
public void onBackPressed() {...}
```

Comment: Да, onBackPressed не углядел, спасибо большое

Comment: @ИванЕмельянов если ответ Вам помог - не забудьте отметить его принятым. На сайте и так много незакрытых вопросов)